# Hive partition columns folders exchanged

Tags: hive, partition

I have a partitioned_table in hive which partitioned by "year,month"，so my hdfs list is

`/user/hive/warehouse/demo.db/employee/year=2017/month=6`

when I used "export" to export table and use "import" to create a new table ,the result is the year and month exchanged, the list is

```
/user/hive/warehouse/demo.db/new_employee/month=6/year=2017
```

my hive version is 1.2.2 and the query:

```
export table employee into /user/hadoop/data

import table new_employee from /user/hadoop/data
```

the partitions in hive have no different with the original table(which one I export). Even I add a new partition, the directory is not changed, it work as '/month=7/year=6'

so what's wrong happened?Thanks for help!

Comment: try `show partitions tablename`   had you find any difference?

Comment: What query did you use for import statement?

Comment: partitions have no changed

Answer (score 0):

Is there issue in the way you are looking at the data as long as you dont have that issue then it is not a problem.by the way this is right export command for exporting the partition table

```
export table employee partition (year="2017", month="6") to 'hdfs_exports_location/employee';
import from 'hdfs_exports_location/employee';
```

well if you have more partition on year and month ..like each year will have 12 month of data i think you may have to do for each month separate command ..i have not tried..just try it with the above command let us know how it is coming

Comment: I know your means, and all people tell me I should export or import the partitions one by one, but I only want to know this problem is  whether or not  a bug?Why did this happened?

Comment: this is not problem..you can say it is restriction from hive ..As of now this is the way to do it..May be in future they might normal way of export like how we will do it for normal tables